# figma outline stroke does not create path for each letter in svg

Tags: css, svg, figma

I'm trying to export a word as svg and get seperate paths for all the letters.

But my svg has only a single path for the entire word.

I use windows desktop figma

my steps:

1. create text word
2. outline stroke
3. remove fill
4. export as svg

```
<svg width="292" height="122" viewBox="0 0 292 122" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M55.7757 116.258L56.499 117.5H57.936H73.632H78.0449L75.7764 113.715L52.2984 74.5401C59.1127 72.5063 64.504 69.0103 68.2837 63.9458C72.6568 58.2141 74.836 51.5836 74.836 44.152C74.836 38.0916 73.4446 32.606 70.6041 27.7665C67.7301 22.8701 63.3984 19.0544 57.7499 16.2798C52.1302 13.472 45.3411 12.132 37.488 12.132H5.08801H2.58801V14.632V115V117.5H5.08801H18.192H20.692V115V76.46H32.595L55.7757 116.258ZM51.7555 32.1455L51.7679 32.1573L51.7805 32.1688C54.7006 34.8522 56.3 38.7238 56.3 44.152C56.3 49.4565 54.7139 53.48 51.7163 56.4841C48.8 59.3137 44.2141 60.948 37.488 60.948H20.692V27.932H37.488C44.3703 27.932 48.9534 29.4992 51.7555 32.1455ZM108.301 36.088V33.588H105.801H92.6974H90.1974V36.088V115V117.5H92.6974H105.801H108.301V115V36.088ZM200.549 60.8454C198.41 51.9819 193.933 44.9307 187.089 39.8464C180.321 34.7471 171.789 32.292 161.687 32.292C153.811 32.292 146.702 34.0633 140.427 37.6636L140.419 37.668L140.411 37.6725C134.234 41.2758 129.403 46.3751 125.931 52.9073C122.439 59.3812 120.739 66.9059 120.739 75.4C120.739 83.9888 122.438 91.6059 125.927 98.1729C129.399 104.709 134.232 109.811 140.411 113.415L140.419 113.42L140.427 113.424C146.702 117.025 153.811 118.796 161.687 118.796C171.626 118.796 180.106 116.279 186.957 111.089L186.966 111.082L186.976 111.074C193.767 105.826 198.292 98.8641 200.537 90.2894L201.358 87.156H198.119H184.007H182.126L181.605 88.9631C180.305 93.4692 177.974 96.8035 174.653 99.1279C171.321 101.46 167.053 102.708 161.687 102.708C154.849 102.708 149.504 100.375 145.411 95.7711C141.34 91.1904 139.131 84.5196 139.131 75.4C139.131 66.3806 141.337 59.8156 145.396 55.3342L145.404 55.3256L145.411 55.3169C149.504 50.7127 154.849 48.38 161.687 48.38C167.035 48.38 171.291 49.6668 174.619 52.08L174.631 52.0886L174.643 52.097C178.094 54.5375 180.405 57.8385 181.599 62.1061L182.111 63.932H184.007H198.119H201.294L200.549 60.8454ZM286.308 117.5H288.808V115V68.488C288.808 60.8863 287.358 54.2642 284.334 48.7285C281.428 43.235 277.337 39.0702 272.07 36.3269C266.877 33.5265 261.093 32.148 254.772 32.148C248.775 32.148 243.264 33.319 238.283 35.7055L238.274 35.7099L238.265 35.7144C235.62 37.0088 233.264 38.6008 231.208 40.4892V8.43999V5.93999H228.708H215.604H213.104V8.43999V115V117.5H215.604H228.708H231.208V115V71.368C231.208 63.5002 233.126 57.9213 236.573 54.2207C240.153 50.4796 244.976 48.524 251.316 48.524C257.574 48.524 262.237 50.4396 265.615 54.0643L265.624 54.0748L265.634 54.0852C268.981 57.5956 270.848 62.883 270.848 70.36V115V117.5H273.348H286.308ZM91.3616 22.4478C93.5696 24.6557 96.3222 25.772 99.4654 25.772C102.534 25.772 105.201 24.639 107.306 22.4225C109.498 20.2189 110.605 17.4752 110.605 14.344C110.605 11.2128 109.498 8.46914 107.306 6.26546C105.201 4.04903 102.534 2.91599 99.4654 2.91599C96.3222 2.91599 93.5696 4.03226 91.3616 6.24022C89.1537 8.44817 88.0374 11.2008 88.0374 14.344C88.0374 17.4871 89.1537 20.2398 91.3616 22.4478Z" stroke="#FFFDFD" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Draw each letter on a separate svg, export, combine the results

Comment: I tried and put paths in the same svg, but all the letters are top of each other. How do you position the letters?

Comment: use transform="translate(X, 0)"  where X is a number. You'll need to determine the appropriate X to position each letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your font probably has some problems with its curves and Figma cannot fix it when doing the outline action. In this case, *Adobe Illustrator usually handles better*.

So here is the solution if you come across this case:

1. Output or make it on **Adobe Illustrator**, outline the object.
2. Copy and paste it to **Figma**.
3. Ungroup and make "unions" according to your preference.

So, here is the SVG code with "separate paths for all the letters":

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 292 122" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M291.22 120.58H268.26V70.94C268.26 64.43 266.74 59.54 263.74 56.39L263.65 56.29C260.73 53.16 256.65 51.61 251.23 51.61C245.81 51.61 241.46 53.22 238.29 56.54C235.2 59.86 233.62 65.05 233.62 71.96V120.59H210.52V4.02002H233.62V36C234.72 35.29 235.87 34.64 237.08 34.05L237.17 34.01C242.38 31.51 248.29 30.23 254.68 30.23C261.43 30.23 267.65 31.74 273.16 34.71C278.81 37.65 283.29 42.18 286.45 48.14C289.61 53.92 291.21 60.97 291.21 69.07V120.58H291.22ZM273.26 115.58H286.22V69.07C286.22 61.82 284.82 55.57 282.05 50.51C279.36 45.43 275.59 41.61 270.82 39.13C266.01 36.54 260.59 35.23 254.68 35.23C248.77 35.23 243.86 36.34 239.27 38.54C236.85 39.73 234.67 41.2 232.81 42.91L228.62 46.76V9.02002H215.52V115.58H228.62V71.95C228.62 63.74 230.65 57.4 234.66 53.1C238.79 48.78 244.36 46.61 251.23 46.61C258.1 46.61 263.44 48.74 267.36 52.95L267.4 52.99C271.29 57.1 273.27 63.14 273.27 70.95V115.59L273.26 115.58Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M161.6 121.88C153.29 121.88 145.74 119.97 139.16 116.21L139.07 116.16C132.52 112.34 127.33 106.88 123.64 99.9301C120 93.0801 118.16 85.0301 118.16 75.9801C118.16 66.9301 120.01 59.0601 123.65 52.3001C127.33 45.3701 132.53 39.9101 139.07 36.0901L139.18 36.0301C145.76 32.2801 153.3 30.3701 161.61 30.3701C172.37 30.3701 181.42 33.0801 188.52 38.4301C195.77 43.8201 200.62 51.3601 202.91 60.8401L204.4 67.0101H180.15L179.13 63.3601C178.1 59.6801 176.15 56.8601 173.17 54.7401L173.09 54.6901C170.1 52.5201 166.35 51.4701 161.63 51.4701C155.61 51.4701 150.91 53.4501 147.27 57.5201L147.22 57.5801C143.47 61.7201 141.58 67.9101 141.58 75.9901C141.58 84.0701 143.48 90.4801 147.23 94.7001C150.88 98.8001 155.59 100.8 161.64 100.8C166.39 100.8 170.17 99.7801 173.17 97.6701C176.07 95.6401 178.03 92.7601 179.15 88.8601L180.19 85.2501H204.54L202.9 91.5201C200.52 100.61 195.68 108.03 188.52 113.59L188.39 113.69C181.21 119.13 172.2 121.89 161.63 121.89L161.6 121.88ZM141.56 111.82L141.59 111.84C147.42 115.18 154.15 116.88 161.61 116.88C171.05 116.88 179.04 114.47 185.34 109.71L185.37 109.68C191.68 104.81 195.94 98.2701 198.04 90.2401H183.93C182.5 95.2101 179.83 99.0801 176.01 101.76C172.19 104.44 167.34 105.79 161.61 105.79C154.16 105.79 148.05 103.17 143.47 98.0101C138.88 92.8501 136.56 85.4401 136.56 75.9801C136.56 66.5201 138.87 59.3401 143.44 54.2801L143.47 54.2401C148.06 49.0801 154.16 46.4601 161.61 46.4601C167.31 46.4601 172.14 47.8501 175.95 50.5901L176.06 50.6701C179.93 53.4101 182.6 57.2401 183.94 62.0101H198.05C196.04 53.7001 191.83 47.1101 185.53 42.4301C179.31 37.7401 171.27 35.3701 161.62 35.3701C154.17 35.3701 147.43 37.0701 141.6 40.4101L141.55 40.4401C135.84 43.7801 131.31 48.5701 128.07 54.6601C124.82 60.6901 123.17 67.8601 123.17 75.9801C123.17 84.1001 124.82 91.4701 128.07 97.5801C131.31 103.68 135.86 108.48 141.58 111.82H141.56Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M110.709 120.58H87.6092V31.6702H110.709V120.58V120.58ZM92.6092 115.58H105.709V36.6702H92.6092V115.58ZM99.3792 28.8502C95.5792 28.8502 92.1592 27.4502 89.5092 24.7902C86.8592 22.1402 85.4492 18.7202 85.4492 14.9202C85.4492 11.1202 86.8492 7.70023 89.5092 5.05023C92.1592 2.40023 95.5792 0.990234 99.3792 0.990234C103.179 0.990234 106.469 2.42023 109.029 5.12023C111.619 7.73023 113.019 11.1302 113.019 14.9202C113.019 18.7102 111.629 22.1102 108.989 24.7602C106.469 27.4202 103.129 28.8502 99.3792 28.8502V28.8502ZM99.3792 5.99023C96.8992 5.99023 94.7592 6.86023 93.0392 8.58023C91.3192 10.3002 90.4492 12.4302 90.4492 14.9202C90.4492 17.4102 91.3192 19.5402 93.0392 21.2602C94.7592 22.9802 96.8892 23.8502 99.3792 23.8502C101.869 23.8502 103.789 22.9802 105.409 21.2802C107.159 19.5202 108.019 17.4002 108.019 14.9202C108.019 12.4402 107.149 10.3202 105.449 8.60023C103.789 6.85023 101.759 5.99023 99.3792 5.99023V5.99023Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M82.37 120.58H54.97L31.07 79.5402H23.1V120.58H0V10.2202H37.4C45.73 10.2202 52.92 11.7002 58.78 14.6302C64.91 17.6402 69.59 21.8402 72.67 27.0902C75.71 32.2602 77.25 38.2002 77.25 44.7402C77.25 52.7402 74.87 59.9102 70.19 66.0502C66.73 70.6902 61.95 74.2002 55.95 76.5002L82.37 120.59V120.58ZM57.85 115.58H73.55L48.42 73.6502L51.5 72.7302C57.87 70.8302 62.82 67.5702 66.2 63.0402C70.22 57.7702 72.26 51.6202 72.26 44.7402C72.26 39.1002 70.95 34.0202 68.37 29.6202C65.79 25.2302 61.82 21.6902 56.57 19.1102C51.4 16.5302 44.96 15.2202 37.41 15.2202H5V115.58H18.1V74.5402H33.94L57.84 115.58H57.85ZM37.4 64.0302H18.1V26.0202H37.4C44.57 26.0202 49.94 27.6702 53.38 30.9202C56.91 34.1802 58.7 38.8302 58.7 44.7402C58.7 50.6502 56.91 55.3002 53.39 58.8402C49.83 62.3002 44.45 64.0402 37.39 64.0402L37.4 64.0302ZM23.1 59.0302H37.4C43.12 59.0302 47.32 57.7702 49.89 55.2702C52.45 52.7002 53.71 49.2402 53.71 44.7302C53.71 40.2202 52.51 36.9102 50.03 34.6202L49.91 34.5102C47.42 32.1902 43.21 31.0102 37.39 31.0102H23.09V59.0302H23.1Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SVG format only supports center stroke. So if you exporting with outside stroke from figma you don't get seperate paths.

Comment: Please add a piece of code.